# Why do we need Support Libraries in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin folder

Tags: xamarin.android

It has been 2 days that my Xamarin project is building and building. I have updated the Android Support Repositories from my SDK Manager. But when I added Android Support Libraries NuGets to my project, It is building and putting downloading stuff in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin
Please can someone help me how can I stop this build process and starting developing my app?

Thanks